# Guess the jackpot number in python

Tags: python, input, while-loop, guess.js

For an assignment i have to make a code that guesses the jackpotnumber from the user. It explains a few steps but it doesn't work for me. Im trying to guess the first digit of the jackpotnumber in this attempt.
I only want help guessing the first digit

I tried this with a few adjustments on the while loop. I tried while true first and i tried using only if/else loops...

```
import random 
digits= int(input("How many digits do you want your jackpot number to have?   "))
jackpotnumber= str(input("What is the lucky number?   "))
if digits == 0:
    print("Choose your digits above zero... ")
if jackpotnumber == 0:
    print("Choose your jackpotnumber with a value above 0..")
if len(jackpotnumber) != digits:
    print("Match your digits and jackpotnumber correctly...")
listj= [int(jackpotnumber)]
listn= []
guess= random.randrange(9)
while guess != listj[0]:
    guess= random.randrange(9)
    if guess == listj[0]:
        listn.append(guess)
        print(listn)
```

The assigment:
In the code we will write (name it jackpot_computer.ipynb), the computer will try to guess a number you enter. Have the computer working to guess a number of 3 digits, in the correct sequence.

In this code i want that the first number of the jackpot guess of the user is the generated by the random guess and if that is the case gets in listn. I also want that the random generator continues until this is achieved. This has to be some kind of loop

Comment: You may want to review the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to understand why you will need to use randrange(10) rather than randrange(9)

Comment: If you put in more work and update your code, respond to this comment and I will help you out, but if I solve the entire problem now you wont learn anything any have real headache in the future. Also people in here dont generally help do an entire task, instead asking a portion you are strugling/getting an error would yield more responses.

Answer (score 0):

your mistakes :

- You should use a `while True` loop to keep asking the user for the number of digits and the jackpot number until they enter valid inputs.
- You should convert the jackpot number to a list of digits using a list comprehension, such as `listj = [int(d) for d in jackpotnumber]`.
- You should use a `for` loop to iterate over each digit of the jackpot number, and use another `while` loop to keep guessing until the computer gets the correct digit.
- You should use `print(''.join(str(d) for d in listn))` to print the list of correct digits as a string.

```py
import random

while True:
    digits = int(
        input("How many digits do you want your jackpot number to have? "))
    if 4 > digits > 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Choose your digits betwenn 0 and 999...")

while True:
    jackpotnumber = input("What is the lucky number? ")
    if jackpotnumber.isdigit() and len(jackpotnumber) == digits:
        break
    else:
        print("Match your digits and jackpotnumber correctly...")

listj = [int(d) for d in jackpotnumber]

listn = []

for i in range(digits):
    guess = random.randint(0, 9)
    while guess != listj[i]:
        guess = random.randint(0, 9)
    listn.append(guess)
    print(''.join(str(d) for d in listn))
```

Also note that this code is not efficient because you are guessing each number using random; you can just increment from 0 to 9.

Comment: this answer before the edit

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to check one digit at a time - just make a pseudo-random guess of a value from a list of possibles.

Something like this:

```
from random import choice

def get_number(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        if (value := input(prompt)).isdecimal():
            if value := int(value):
                return value
        print("Not a valid positive integer")

while True:
    digits = get_number("How many digits do you want your jackpot number to have? ")
    lucky = get_number("What is the lucky number? ")
    if len(str(lucky)) == digits:
        break
    print("The length of your lucky number doesn't match")

possibles = list(range(1, 10**digits))
nguesses = 1
while True:
    if (guess := choice(possibles)) == lucky:
        print(f"Computer has matched your lucky number after {nguesses} guesses")
        break
    print(f"Incorrect computer {guess=}")
    possibles.remove(guess)
    nguesses += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

So I came up with this script, It can take input based on the digit you want 1 to 9 and then based on the actual number it tries to guess.
[image]

```
import random
    
    def get_user_input():
        while True:
            try:
                num_digits = int(input("Enter the number of digits for the jackpot number: "))
                if 0 < num_digits <= 9:
                    return num_digits
                else:
                    print("Please enter a number between 1 and 9.")
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
    
    def validate_lucky_number(num_digits):
        while True:
            jackpot_number = input(f"Enter your {num_digits}-digit lucky number: ")
            if jackpot_number.isdigit() and len(jackpot_number) == num_digits:
                return jackpot_number
            else:
                print(f"Please enter a {num_digits}-digit numeric lucky number.")
    
    def computer_guess_jackpot(num_digits, jackpot_number):
        guess = ""
        for i in range(num_digits):
            digit_guess = str(random.randint(0, 9))
            print(f"Computer's guess for digit {i + 1}: {digit_guess}")
            guess += digit_guess
    
            if guess == jackpot_number:
                print("Congratulations! The computer guessed the entire jackpot number:", guess)
                return
            elif guess == jackpot_number[:i + 1]:
                print("Correct! Moving to the next digit.")
            else:
                print("Incorrect. Trying next digit.")
    
    def main():
        num_digits = get_user_input()
        jackpot_number = validate_lucky_number(num_digits)
        
        print("\nStarting the guessing game!\n")
        
        computer_guess_jackpot(num_digits, jackpot_number)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: The code does `guess += digit_guess` before checking whether the guess is correct, and it never removes the guessed digit if it is incorrect.